# Customizable product in opencart

Tags: opencart

I am creating a online mug printing e shop. I want to allow user to apply there own images on mugs is there any module in opencart.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.  There are a lot of modules out there that will allow a user to add custom text to currently overlaid images, but those images are pre-loaded.  I was looking into doing the same thing(not the mug, but the upload of the picture) Opencart currently does not offer an off the shelf module specifically for images, however you can get a file upload module:

http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=1887

For conventional text options with an image overlay you might want to consider the following as well, it is for a t-shirt company, the user can add the text to the tshirt image already on page, change colours, of the image and text, fonts, etc...  might be a good option for mugs.

http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=24&t=3998&start=20

They are not what you are looking for but unfortunately nothing currently exists.  If you have the time, patience and money you can easily get a freelancer to create one for you.  I would recommend them creating one not in your site specifically but to create a module that you can upload to your site, this way you could actually turn around and sell it on the Opencart Store, maybe make some of your money back - lots of people out there looking for the same sort of thing!

So in short there is currently no solution other then the links above or to get a freelancer to create one for you.

Cheers,

A

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a similar plugin to serve your purpose of Mug printing eshop.

Here is the Custom T-shirt module for Opencart, but you can use it for Custom Mug too, as they are having the feature to drag the logo and texts anywhere of the product.

http://codecanyon.net/item/opencart-custom-tshirt-design/4943029?ref=wpproducts

So, if you use a Mug's picture instead of T-shirt it may serve you well.

Moreover I have heard from their team that they are going to release the Custom Mug Design Maker extension soon. So, you can follow them stay connected.

Thanks
Shondhi

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is an old question, but I think that another options will be welcome for future users with same needs. 
This options should be considered when you need to customize frames or another products
Custom product Builder http://wedoweb.com.au/store/opencart-extensions